# Search query only working for first row of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm having an exasperating problem. I have a dataframe with two rows: the first row contains tuples that consist of a tweet and its date, both as string data ('text', 'date'). I wish to query each row for the presence of a specific term, and return a new dataframe containing only those tweets that have the term I want. I know that both rows have several entries with the relevant term. Here's my code:

```
data = pd.read_pickle('filepath.pkl') 

dict_twit = {k:[] for k in data.index} ## creates empty dict for relevant tweets to go into

for i in data.index: ### data has a text-based index
    try:
        relevant_tweet = []
        for j in range(len(data.loc[i])):
            if 'query' in data.loc[i][j][0].lower():
                relevant_tweet.append(data.loc[i][j])
        dict_twit[i] = relevant_tweet
    except TypeError: ### The are empty cells in some rows
        dict_twit[i] = []

tweets_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_twit, orient = 'index')
```

However, when I run the code, only the first row of tweets_df has any text; the second row is empty. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: here's some sample data:

```
Index                Entries
digi_marketing_20th: ('RT @bigbomglobal: ? ? ?  Bigbom Interview with Dr. Long Vuong, Founder and CEO of Tomochain at MOU SIGNING CEREMONY ', '20/03/2018') , ('The latest ? eDGTL? News ?!  #digitalmarketing', '20/03/2018')
digi_marketing_21st: ('#DigitalMarketing See Top 3 Content creation tools Updated for 2017 ', '21/03/2018'), ('RT @sheerazhasan: Sheeraz, Inc digital marketing strategy for your business or brand! #digitalmarketing #socialmedia', '21/03/2018')
```

Comment: Can you please provide a few lines of input sample data?

Comment: Sure, just did, though the data is ugly and not easily shoe-horned into SO formatting.

Comment: To be clear, are items in `Entries` column tuples of tuples? Currently, they don't seem a valid type. Seems like `(('XXX', 'date1'), ('YYY', 'date2'))` but the outer brackets are missing.

Comment: Sorry, this is my crappy formatting. The comma separator should be a column separator too. Thus

col_1 = ('XXX', 'date1')
col_2 = ('YYYY', 'date2')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more efficient way using `collections.defaultdict`.

Prefer `df.itertuples` over `df.iterrows` for performance reasons, as the latter has a large overhead.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['digi_marketing_20th:', ('RT @bigbomglobal: ? ? ?  Bigbom Interview with Dr. Long Vuong, Founder and CEO of Tomochain at MOU SIGNING CEREMONY ', '20/03/2018') , ('The latest ? eDGTL? News ?!  #digitalmarketing', '20/03/2018')],
                   ['digi_marketing_21st:', ('#DigitalMarketing See Top 3 Content creation tools Updated for 2017 ', '21/03/2018'), ('RT @sheerazhasan: Sheeraz, Inc digital marketing strategy for your business or brand! #digitalmarketing #socialmedia', '21/03/2018')]],
                  columns=['Index', 'Col1', 'Col2'])

#                   Index                                               Col1  \
# 0  digi_marketing_20th:  (RT @bigbomglobal: ? ? ?  Bigbom Interview wit...   
# 1  digi_marketing_21st:  (#DigitalMarketing See Top 3 Content creation ...   

d = defaultdict(list)

for idx, row in enumerate(df.itertuples()):
    for tweet, date in row[2:]:
        if 'digital' in tweet.lower():
            d[idx].append(tweet)

# defaultdict(list,
#             {0: ['The latest ? eDGTL? News ?!  #digitalmarketing'],
#              1: ['#DigitalMarketing See Top 3 Content creation tools Updated for 2017 ',
#               'RT @sheerazhasan: Sheeraz, Inc digital marketing strategy for your business or brand! #digitalmarketing #socialmedia']})
```

Comment: Great, thanks, excellent solution! Much neater, especially given that the actual data is much bigger.Thanks!